# Which all IDE will support python scripts?

Tags: ide

My laptop is working in windows 7 OS. I want to start working with Python, But i don't have Linux in my system. Can you suggest any IDE which will help me to start my Python scripting under windows OS???

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Anaconda Python packages and run them with Komodo Edit IDE. Other option is to use eclipse, which is quite bulky. A comprehensive summary is available at [Choosing Python IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)